# CUDA Speed Slower than expected - Image Processing

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I am new to CUDA development and wanted to write a simple benchmark to test some image processing feasibility. I have 32 images that are each 720x540, one byte per pixel greyscale.

I am running benchmarks for 10 seconds, and counting how many times they are able to process. There are three benchmarks I am running:

- The first is just transferring the images into the GPU global memory, via cudaMemcpy
- The second is transferring and processing the images.
- The third is running the equivalent test on a CPU.

For a starting, simple test, the image processing is just counting the number of pixels above a certain greyscale value. I'm finding that accessing global memory on the GPU is very slow. I have my benchmark structured such that it creates one block per image, and one thread per row in each image. Each thread counts its pixels into a shared memory array, after which the first thread sums them up (See below).

The issue I am having is that this all runs very slowly - about 50fps. Much slower than a CPU version - about 230fps. If I comment out the pixel value comparison, resulting in just a count of all pixels, I get 6x the performance. I tried using texture memory but didn't see a performance gain. I am running a Quadro K2000. Also: the image copy only benchmark is able to copy at around 330fps, so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Any help / pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
__global__ void ThreadPerRowCounter(int Threshold, int W, int H, U8 **AllPixels, int *AllReturns)
{
    extern __shared__ int row_counts[];//this parameter to kernel call "<<<, ,>>>" sets the size

    //see here for indexing https://blog.usejournal.com/cuda-thread-indexing-fb9910cba084
    int myImage = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    int myStartRow = (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
    unsigned char *imageStart = AllPixels[myImage];

    unsigned char *pixelStart   = imageStart + myStartRow * W;
    unsigned char *pixelEnd     = pixelStart + W;
    unsigned char *pixelItr     = pixelStart;

    int row_count = 0;
    while(pixelItr < pixelEnd)
    {
        if (*pixelItr > Threshold) //REMOVING THIS LINE GIVES 6x PERFORMANCE
        {
            row_count++;
        }
        pixelItr++;
    }
    row_counts[myStartRow] = row_count;

    __syncthreads();

    if (myStartRow == 0)
    {//first thread sums up for the while image

        int image_count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++)
        {
            image_count += row_counts[i];
        }
        AllReturns[myImage] = image_count;
    }
}




extern "C" void cuda_Benchmark(int nImages, int W, int H, U8** AllPixels, int *AllReturns, int Threshold)
{   
    ThreadPerRowCounter<<<nImages, H, sizeof(int)*H>>> (
        Threshold,
        W, H,
        AllPixels,
        AllReturns);

    //wait for all blocks to finish
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
```

Comment: a thread per row is a really bad design choice for GPU.  A thread per column should work better

Comment: I assume the layout of the image in memory would impact this greatly. In my case I did lay the images out row-major. I assume the reason for this is based on how many threads are accessing the same memory bank simultaneously?

Also, I was just able to run my same spec on a GTX 1080 Ti, and the performance was much better, about fps on the GPU.

Comment: I should also mention I am using a single cudaMalloc per image, and copying the entire image buffer, in a row-major layout, in a  single cudaMemcpy.

Comment: For the stated algorithm, counting the number of pixels that exceed a threshold, I don't think image layout in memory really matters.   You can go through the pixels in any order and still get the right answer.   But the way you issue work to threads, and the patterns that threads use when they access memory certainly does matter for performance.  And, yes,  a K2000 is one of the slowest GPUs out there.

Comment: According to my testing, switching to column thread operation vs. row thread operation, plus implementation of a canonical parallel reduction vs. what you have, results in about a 25x speedup of the kernel on Quadro K2000.

Comment: I really appreciate this feedback, thank you. I believe I can work out the reduction myself. I'm very interested in hearing more on why having the column-based approach is so much better than row, despite the memory layout of the image data. Not that I'm disputing you, just trying to understand where the performance gains could be found for future applications. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780710/dont-understand-why-column-addition-faster-than-row-in-cuda

Comment: Thank you - your description in this thread appears to confirm what I was thinking regarding memory layout and is very informative in providing the details of how the warps access memory efficiently. I don't know if I can give you the "correct answer" designation in a comment, but would like to credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two changes to your kernel design can result in a significant speedup:

1. Perform the operations column-wise instead of row-wise.  The general background for why this matters/helps is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780710/dont-understand-why-column-addition-faster-than-row-in-cuda).
2. Replace your final operation with a [canonical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).

According to my testing, those 2 changes result in ~22x speedup in kernel performance:

```
$ cat t49.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
typedef unsigned char U8;
__global__ void ThreadPerRowCounter(int Threshold, int W, int H, U8 **AllPixels, int *AllReturns)
{
    extern __shared__ int row_counts[];//this parameter to kernel call "<<<, ,>>>" sets the size

    //see here for indexing https://blog.usejournal.com/cuda-thread-indexing-fb9910cba084
    int myImage = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    int myStartRow = (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
    unsigned char *imageStart = AllPixels[myImage];

    unsigned char *pixelStart   = imageStart + myStartRow * W;
    unsigned char *pixelEnd     = pixelStart + W;
    unsigned char *pixelItr     = pixelStart;

    int row_count = 0;
    while(pixelItr < pixelEnd)
    {
        if (*pixelItr > Threshold) //REMOVING THIS LINE GIVES 6x PERFORMANCE
        {
            row_count++;
        }
        pixelItr++;
    }
    row_counts[myStartRow] = row_count;

    __syncthreads();

    if (myStartRow == 0)
    {//first thread sums up for the while image

        int image_count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++)
        {
            image_count += row_counts[i];
        }
        AllReturns[myImage] = image_count;
    }
}



__global__ void ThreadPerColCounter(int Threshold, int W, int H, U8 **AllPixels, int *AllReturns, int rsize)
{
    extern __shared__ int col_counts[];//this parameter to kernel call "<<<, ,>>>" sets the size
    int myImage = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
    unsigned char *imageStart = AllPixels[myImage];
    int myStartCol = (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x);
    int col_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) if (imageStart[myStartCol+i*W]> Threshold) col_count++;
    col_counts[threadIdx.x] = col_count;
    __syncthreads();
    for (int i = rsize; i > 0; i>>=1){
      if ((threadIdx.x+i < W) && (threadIdx.x < i)) col_counts[threadIdx.x] += col_counts[threadIdx.x+i];
    __syncthreads();}
    if (!threadIdx.x) AllReturns[myImage] = col_counts[0];
}

void cuda_Benchmark(int nImages, int W, int H, U8** AllPixels, int *AllReturns, int Threshold)
{
    ThreadPerRowCounter<<<nImages, H, sizeof(int)*H>>> (
        Threshold,
        W, H,
        AllPixels,
        AllReturns);

    //wait for all blocks to finish
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
unsigned next_power_of_2(unsigned v){
        v--;
        v |= v >> 1;
        v |= v >> 2;
        v |= v >> 4;
        v |= v >> 8;
        v |= v >> 16;
        v++;
        return v;}

void cuda_Benchmark1(int nImages, int W, int H, U8** AllPixels, int *AllReturns, int Threshold)
{
    int rsize = next_power_of_2(W/2);
    ThreadPerColCounter<<<nImages, W, sizeof(int)*W>>> (
        Threshold,
        W, H,
        AllPixels,
        AllReturns, rsize);

    //wait for all blocks to finish
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

int main(){
    const int my_W = 720;
    const int my_H = 540;
    const int n_img = 128;
    const int my_thresh = 10;

    U8 **img_p, **img_ph;
    U8 *img, *img_h;
    int *res, *res_h, *res_h1;
    img_ph = (U8 **)malloc(n_img*sizeof(U8*));
    cudaMalloc(&img_p, n_img*sizeof(U8*));
    cudaMalloc(&img, n_img*my_W*my_H*sizeof(U8));
    img_h = new U8[n_img*my_W*my_H];
    for (int i = 0; i < n_img*my_W*my_H; i++) img_h[i] = rand()%20;
    cudaMemcpy(img, img_h, n_img*my_W*my_H*sizeof(U8), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_img; i++) img_ph[i] = img+my_W*my_H*i;
    cudaMemcpy(img_p, img_ph, n_img*sizeof(U8*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc(&res, n_img*sizeof(int));
    cuda_Benchmark(n_img, my_W, my_H, img_p, res, my_thresh);
    res_h = new int[n_img];
    cudaMemcpy(res_h, res, n_img*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cuda_Benchmark1(n_img, my_W, my_H, img_p, res, my_thresh);
    res_h1 = new int[n_img];
    cudaMemcpy(res_h1, res, n_img*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_img; i++) if (res_h[i] != res_h1[i]) {std::cout << "mismatch at: " << i << " was: " << res_h1[i] << " should be: " << res_h[i] << std::endl; return 0;}
}
$ nvcc -o t49 t49.cu -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc
$ cuda-memcheck ./t49
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvprof ./t49
==1756== NVPROF is profiling process 1756, command: ./t49
==1756== Profiling application: ./t49
==1756== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   72.02%  54.325ms         1  54.325ms  54.325ms  54.325ms  ThreadPerRowCounter(int, int, int, unsigned char**, int*)
                   24.71%  18.639ms         2  9.3195ms  1.2800us  18.638ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                    3.26%  2.4586ms         1  2.4586ms  2.4586ms  2.4586ms  ThreadPerColCounter(int, int, int, unsigned char**, int*, int)
                    0.00%  3.1040us         2  1.5520us  1.5360us  1.5680us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
      API calls:   43.63%  59.427ms         3  19.809ms  18.514us  59.159ms  cudaMalloc
                   41.70%  56.789ms         2  28.394ms  2.4619ms  54.327ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                   14.02%  19.100ms         4  4.7749ms  17.749us  18.985ms  cudaMemcpy
                    0.52%  705.26us        96  7.3460us     203ns  327.21us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.05%  69.268us         1  69.268us  69.268us  69.268us  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.04%  50.688us         1  50.688us  50.688us  50.688us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.04%  47.683us         2  23.841us  14.352us  33.331us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.00%  3.1770us         1  3.1770us  3.1770us  3.1770us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  1.5610us         3     520ns     249ns     824ns  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  1.0550us         2     527ns     266ns     789ns  cuDeviceGet
$
```

(Quadro K2000, CUDA 9.2.148, Fedora Core 27)

(The next_power_of_2 code is lifted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466242/1695960))

I don't claim correctness for this code or any other code that I post. Anyone using any code I post does so at their own risk. I merely claim that I have attempted to address the questions in the original posting, and provide some explanation thereof. I am not claiming my code is defect-free, or that it is suitable for any particular purpose. Use it (or not) at your own risk.